Swap API - Balance change is not displayed when using Jupiter swap API
I'm using jupiter quote/swap endpoints to get transaction string. https://www.quicknode.com/docs/solana/swap
But when signing transaction, wallets don't display balance change at all, even though it gets correctly performed after confirming this transaction.
Simulating transaction on main net succeeds.
const connection = new Connection('https://solana-rpc.publicnode.com')
const serializedTx = result.transactionString // the swapTransaction string of /swap endpoint
const binaryString = atob(serializedTx);
const transactionBuffer = Uint8Array.from(binaryString, (char) => char.charCodeAt(0));
const versionedTransaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(transactionBuffer);
console.log(await connection.simulateTransaction(versionedTransaction)) // success

const signedTransaction = await wallet.value.adapter.signTransaction(versionedTransaction);

console.log("Signed Transaction:", signedTransaction);

But when sign happens, i see window like this:

Expected result:


I think the question is more about Phantom policies. Try to reach out to the email specified in the warning.

Yeah so those warning likely because i use ngrok.
Basically if there were any warnings like those or unsufficient balance warning, i was not seeing this balance change with token names.
Once i didn't have any of warnings - i had balance change display correctly.
PS In case anyone else will have similar problem: I also encountered issue where adding too small transaction instruction transfer amount(0.0001 SOL) over SwapAPI transaction, also resulted in unsufficient balance warning(even though there was more than enough) without any balance change.
For 0.001 transfer amount all good though..
